# How to implement or avoid masking for transformer?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, natural-language-processing, python, pytorch, transformer

When it comes to using Transformers for image captioning is there any reason to use masking?

I currently have a resnet101 encoder and am trying to use the features as the input for a transformer model in order to generate a caption for the image, is there any need to use masking? and what would I mask if I did need to?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a library such as [Trax](https://github.com/google/trax) which contains great submodules for various Transformers (Skipping, BERT, Vanilla and Reformer) you can use the inbuilt `trax.data.inputs.add_loss_weights()` function and provide a value for the `id_to_mask` parameter.

Example Usage:

```
train_generator = trax.data.inputs.add_loss_weights(
data_generator(batch_size, x_train, y_train,vocab['<PAD>'], True),
id_to_mask=vocab['<PAD>'])
```

Here are some resources for building Transformers in Trax:

- [Named Entity Recognition with Reformer](https://github.com/SauravMaheshkar/Trax-Examples/blob/main/NLP/NER%20using%20Reformer.ipynb) (Masking Implemented) and the associated [blog post](https://sauravmaheshkar.github.io/fastpages/transformers/jupyter/nlp/2020/11/29/_11_19_NER_Using_Reformer.html) (contains an in-depth explanation of NER and Transformers)
- [Deep N-Gram Models](https://github.com/SauravMaheshkar/Trax-Examples/blob/main/NLP/Deep%20N-Gram.ipynb) (without masking but I recommend you go through these first to get a hang of the library)

Comment: The associated blog post link gives me a 404. Is there an up to date version?

Comment: Here's the updated [link](https://sauravmaheshkar.github.io/blog/blog/NER-Using-Reformer/). Sorry I moved my blog from fastpages 

Comment: @SauravMaheshkar It seems the link is still not working.

Comment: I keep changing blog platforms a lot so the links keep changing. I'll make it a point to add a permalink next time. For now, the link is [this](https://sauravmaheshkar.github.io/blog/projects/NER-Using-Reformer/).  I apologize but the Markdown parser is still not fixed so the latex is going to be hard to read. If you necessarily need the latex rendered visit this [alternative link](https://sauravvmaheshkar.gitbook.io/saurav-maheshkar/projects/named-entity-recognition-using-reformers/named-entity-recognition-a-brief-overview)